# angular 5 http post header response

Tags: angular, http, http-headers, response, angular5

I am not sure if this is a bug or i am missing something but i am working on the latest version of angular.

I am posting a request to the API, and the API return an empty body but I want to return the response header back to the component.

the code below

```
add (productslist: number[]):Observable<HttpHeaderResponse> {
    return this.http.put<Response>(this.PutUrl, productslist, this.putheader).pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log("add")),
       // Response(),
        catchError(this.handleError<number[]>(`addShoppingCart `)),
        map((res:HttpHeaderResponse) =>{ 
            console.log(res);
            return res}  ) 
      ); 

  }
```

`res` is undefined am I doing something wrong here or is there a known bug in the latest version.

Comment: Did you look at this? https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code:

```
add (productslist: number[]):Observable<HttpHeaderResponse> {
    return this.http.put<Response>(this.PutUrl, productslist, {observe: 'response', headers: this.putheader}).pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log("add")),
       // Response(),
        catchError(this.handleError<number[]>(`addShoppingCart `)),
        map((res:HttpHeaderResponse) =>{ 
            console.log(res);
            return res}  ) 
      ); 

  }
```

> **observe**: It defines whether we want complete response or body only or events only. We need to assign values for observe property such as
>   **response** for complete response, **body** for response with body and **events**
>   for response with events.